# code read few lines from a text file in C

Tags: c, scanf

I want to create a program to read the first 3 lines from a text file that has 9 lines. Please help me with the below code and point out what I am doing wrong.

Further is it possible to read 3-6 lines in the text file?

Thanks for any help.

```
char name1[20], name2[20], name3[20];
FILE *fp = fopen("names.txt", "r");
while(3 == fscanf(fp, "%20[^\n]%*c%20[^\n]%*c%20[^\n]%*c", name1, name2, name3)){
    printf("%s, %s, %s\n", name1, name2, name3);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time you find yourself naming variables with numeric suffixes, you should probably be using an array. So instead of three arrays `name1`, `name2`, and `name3`, use a 2-dimensional array:

```
#define LINES 3
#define LINESIZE 20
char name[LINES][LINESIZE];
```

Then you can read the lines in a loop, and it will be easy to change the number of lines.

```
for (int i = 0; i < LINES; i++) {
    if (fgets(name[i], LINESIZE, fp) == NULL) {
        break;
    }
    // Remove trailing newline if it's there
    size_z len = strlen(name[i]);
    if (name[i][len-1] == '\n') {
        name[i][len-1] = '\0';
    }
}
```